# Extending Group in LibGdx

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I created a group in my Project's play screen. The group contains a number of images and buttons as actors.

```
Group newGroup = new Group();
```

inside show()

```
newGroup.addActor(bg);
stage.addActor(newGroup);
```

This works well.But I want to add a lot more things in the group.Also I need to create few more groups also.So I think I can create  new classes that extends the Group. Actually I want to use a modular way to create these groups.

```
public class newGroup extends Group {
 //want to add actors here-buttons,images and other scene2d elements
}

public class actor extends Actor{

}
```

I have something like this in mind to do but I don't know how to do this effectively, so that I can move and scale the group items and access in play screen.
Please tell me how can I properly extend the Group in LibGdx and access it in play screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need to do same things as in your example but do it your extended class. Maybe my short example will help you.

There are SKIN variable in the examples below. I haven't showed how to load the skin. Read about Scene2D.ui to understand the meaning of the SKIN.

First example (with no extending):

```
Group group = new Group();
TextButton b = new TextButton(SKIN, "Press Me");
Label l = new Label(SKIN, "Some text");
b.setPosition(0, 0); //in groups coordinates
l.setPosition(0, 100);
group.addActor(l);
group.addActor(b);

stage.addActor(group);
```

You can do the same with extending:

```
public class MyGroup extends Group {
     private TextButton b;
     private Label l;

     public MyGroup() {
          b = new TextButton(SKIN, "Press me");
          l = new Label(SKIN, "Some text");
          b.setPosition(0, 0); //in coordinates of group
          l.setPosition(0, 100);
          //now we will add button and label to the our extended group.
          this.addActor(b);
          this.addActor(l);
          //"this" is unnecessary. I write this because it 
          //may be more clear for you to understand the code.
          //"this" is our extended group and we add actors to it.
     }

}
```

So, now you can create our new group and add it to the Stage:

```
MyGroup myGroup = new MyGroup();
myGroup.setPosition(200, 200); //also in `stage` coords.
stage.addActor(myGroup);
```